# How to write a BASH command in C which use stdin and stdout

Tags: pipe, c, stdout, stdin

I want to write a programme where I compile a C programme, and save it where BASH recognises programmes are (/usr/bin or somewhere).

For usage I want to run in the terminal

```
$ c_programme <file_input> | <programme_to_pipe_stdout>
```

I can see that with the popen() function I can use ffmpeg to process video:

```
FILE *pipein = popen("ffmpeg -i teapot.mp4 -f image2pipe -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -", "r");
FILE *pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i - -f mp4 -q:v 50 -an -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4", "w");
```

But in the above teapot.mp4 was already specified in the code, not input into the C programme when the programme was run in BASH. How can I make a variable in the C code which will read from the shell?

Similarly, I don't want to output to a file, I just want to output to stdout, so I can pipe it. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are 1000 tutorials about this topic to be found in the internet. Search for `stdin` and `stdout`. You may also better helped at stackoverflow.

Comment: I recommend taking a quick C tutorial such as https://www.programiz.com/c-programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make a variable in the C code which will read from the shell?

A C program can get the arguments passed to it on the command line by declaring `main` as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, after which `argv[0]` refers to the name of the program, `argv[1]` is the first argument, `argv[2]` is the second, and so on up to `argv[argc-1]`. The end is also indicate by `argv[argc]` being a null pointer.

For example, the output of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s.\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

when executed as `foo Argument1 Argument2` is:

```
argv[0] = foo.
argv[1] = Argument1.
argv[2] = Argument2.
```

> Similarly, I don't want to output to a file, I just want to output to stdout, so I can pipe it. How would I do this?

Use `printf`, `puts`, or `putchar`.

Comment: The next step would be to declare a string variable, use a function such as `sprintf` to generate the command, and pass it to `popen` call. Declaring the string would require dynamic allocation which would require functions `malloc`/`calloc` and `strlen`.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone, that is exactly the type of explanation I was after. Will there be an output stream which I can pipe into another programme?